# Prove with delta-epsilon definition: $\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x^2-9}{x^2-3x}=2$

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

> Prove with delta-epsilon definition: $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 3} \frac{x^2-9}{x^2-3x}=2$

I started with the following inequality:
$$
\Big|\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-3x}-2\Big|<\epsilon.
$$
Then I could not progress after this:
$$
\Big|\frac{x+3}{x}-2\Big|<\epsilon.
$$
Could anyone help me to find $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)?$

Comment: You may assume that $\epsilon<1$ or even $\epsilon<0.1$.

Comment: But by definition we can choose any positive real number for $\epsilon$. Could you clarify your comment?

Comment: Given any $\epsilon$, for any $N>1$, $\frac{\epsilon }N<\epsilon$ so you may replace $\frac{\epsilon} N$ in the inequality to find $\delta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|\frac{x^2-9}{x^2-3x} -2| = |\frac{-x^2+6x-9}{x^2-3x}| = |\frac{x^2-6x+9}{x^2-3x}| = |\frac{x-3}{x}| = |x-3||\frac{1}{x}|$

You want $|x-3||\frac{1}{x}| < \epsilon$ when $|x-3|<\delta$ so we can bound $\delta \leq 1$ then $|x-3|<1$ so $|\frac{1}{x}| < \frac{1}{2}$
so we choose $\delta = \min\{1, 2\epsilon\}$ then
$$|x-3||1/x| <\frac{1}{2}2\epsilon = \epsilon $$

Comment: Thanks. But could you explain why you bounded $\delta$ and how did you get $|\frac{1}{x}| < \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @IlhomSadriddinov you bound $\delta$ so you can find a bound on $|1/x|$, if $|x-3|<1$ then $x \in (2,4)$. Since $|1/x|$ strictly decreasing on $x>0$ then the largest value of $|1/x|$ on the interval is less than $|1/2|$ .